# Find all complex numbers $z$ such that $Re((z−1)^2)= 0$ and $|z+1|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do you find all complex numbers $z$ such that $Re((z−1)^2)= 0$ and $|z+1|=2$

I don't know where should I start since I only know the real part.

Answer (score 1):

First, $|z+1|=2$ is the equation of a circle centered at $\Omega(-1)$.
Then, if $z=x+iy$, $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$,
$$(z-1)^2=(x-1)^2-y^2+2i(x-1)y$$
so ${\rm Re}((z-1)^2)=0$ is equivalent to 
$$(x-1)^2-y^2=0\iff (x-1-y)(x-1+y)=0\iff y=x-1\text{ or }y=-x+1$$
Draw the circle, the two lines, figure out the position of the intersections. Or substitute $y$ in the circle equation to find the corresponding $x$...

Comment: I get (1,0) at the intersection and thats the set?

Comment: $(1,0)$ is a solution... But it's not the only one. There is also $(-1,2)$ and $(-1,-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = x + iy$. Then $z^2 = x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi$

$$(z-1)^2 = z^2 - 2z + 1 \\ = (x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi) - 2(x + iy) + 1 =
(x^2 - 2x - y^2 + 1) + i(2xy - 2y)$$

So $Re((z-1)^2) = x^2 - 2x - y^2 + 1 = 0$, which is a pair of intersecting lines.

$$|z+1|^2 = |(x + 1) + iy|^2 \\= (x+1)^2 + y^2 = 4$$

which is a circle of radius 2 centered at $(-1, 0)$

The set you desire will be the intersection of these objects.

Answer (score -1):

With $$z=x+iy$$ we get $$\Re((x-1)^2-y^2+2y(x-1)i)=(x-1)^2-y^2=0$$ and $$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}=2$$